# Move Listtile after it has been completed to another position

Tags: flutter, web-applications, flutter-layout, positioning

I'm hoping is someone is able to help me with this.

I would like the listTile to move below where it says "Under Review" after a user submits any of the information in the listtiles. I have tried using Positioned widget but it did nor work. It should work in a away, where whichever the user decides to submit first that specific listtile goes first right below "under Review"

I have added the code below. Thanks for the help guys!

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:parcel_you_driver_app/Screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:parcel_you_driver_app/global/global.dart';

class DriverOnboarding extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<DriverOnboarding> createState() => _DriverOnboardingState();
}

class _DriverOnboardingState extends State<DriverOnboarding> {

 //bool isFileUnderReview = false;

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: const Text('Cancel')
    );
    Widget logOutButton = TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const WelcomePage()));
        },
        child: const Text('Log out')
    );

    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      content: const Text("Are you sure you want to log out?"),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        logOutButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: <Widget> [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Tooltip(
              message: 'Log out',
              child: IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                onPressed: () {
                  showAlertDialog(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('ParcelYou',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children:<Widget>[
            Row(
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text("Welcome,",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
             //Profile Photo
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 10),
                    child: Text("Profile photo",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                    child: Text("This will appear in your driver portal"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),

             //Vehicle Details
             GestureDetector(
               onTap: () {},
               child: const Card(
                 elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 10),
                    child: Text("Vehicle details",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
                    child: Text("Add the color, year, make and model of your vehicle"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
            ),
             ),

            // Driver's License
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 15),
                    child: Text("Driver's license",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                    child: Text("This will help us confirm your identity"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //proof of work eligibility
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 10),
                    child: Text("Proof of work eligibility",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                    child: Text("This will help us determine you are eligible to work in your country"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //vehicle Registration
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 10),
                    child: Text("Vehicle registration",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                    child: Text("Vehicle registration is required to deliver"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //vehicle insurance
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 10),
                    child: Text("Vehicle insurance",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                    child: Text("Vehicle insurance is required to deliver"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            //guidelines and expectations

            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Card(
                elevation: 3,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.article,color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 10),
                    child: Text("Guidelines and expectations",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                    child: Text("Please read and agree to our guidelines and expectations to start driving"),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 50),

            Row(
              children:const <Widget> [
                 Padding(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                   child: Text("Under Review",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                 ),
              ],

            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have small number and fixed of listTiles
you can just add a bool for every listTile and make it true when it's submitted, and if it's true show any widget you want under the "Under Review".

```
    bool profilePhoto =false; 
    .
    .
    //when profile photo submitted
    onTap(){
      setState((){
         profilePhoto =true;
      });
}

//add this when you want to put the widget
profilePhoto?YOURWIDGET():Container(),
```

YOURWIDGET() is the widget you want to be shown below the "Under Review".

you can hide the listtile that is submitted using the same bool variable

This will basically show the widget you want when it's submitted and show nothing when it's not